# How to show something in Gmail message between subject and body?

Tags: gmail, html-email

I need to paste table (details of event) beetwen subject and body of the gmail message. Watch the example image https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQqqU.jpg
It's some feature of Gmail, I think. It looks like invitation of google calendar event, but it's not the same. 
How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is schema.org markup - info to set up and process for approval is available here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/